# Change axis ticks formatting and add lines to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an x-axis which is categorical.  I would like to have the ticks along the axis be boxing the labels, as opposed to centered above them.  I would also like to have vertical lines in the plot separating each category along the x-axis.

Here is an example data set:

```
df <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
  x      y
 Cat1   2.3
 Cat2   2.7
 Cat3   1.0 
 Cat1   0.9
 Cat2   9.3
 Cat3   3.3"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
```

Here is the resultant plot:

```
 ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw(base_size=16)+
  opts(panel.grid.major=theme_blank())
```

[image: before]

And here is roughly what I would like the plot to look like:

[image: after]

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Ramnath provided a clever solution, assuming you didn't actually want ticks between Cat1/Cat2 and Cat2/Cat3. More generally, [this](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/45bc27bf163920bc/1950ff7bda8e4784?lnk=gst&q=labels+between+axis+ticks#1950ff7bda8e4784) thread suggests that this isn't, in general, possible in ggplot2. It [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530933/placing-the-x-axis-labels-between-period-ticks) easily be done in base graphics, though.

Comment: Hmmm..that's too bad.  I'm using ggplot2 because there are some other manipulations that I have yet to figure out how to implement in base graphics.  I'll go with Ramnath's workaround for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add a few lines to your plotting code

```
# YOUR CODE
pl0 = ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw(base_size=16)+
  opts(panel.grid.major=theme_blank())

# MY ADDITION
pl1 = pl0 + opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5)
```

Comment: you can use vectors for the xintercept argument. So you can replace the two geom_vline statements with just one geom_vline(xintercept = c(1.5, 2.5))